# Presenting Code with preview

Tags: html, markdown, live-preview, slideshow

I have recently discovered [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/). Google offers some very interesting [videos and presentations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8OJ7ih8EE7s&list=PLRAVCSU_HVYu-zlRaqArF8Ytwz1jlMOIM) for their platform. There are some slides that contain a title, simple text, **HTML code** and **its preview**. The preview seems to be interactive. What software can I use to help me get such results?

Please, take a look at this slide in their video: [link](http://youtu.be/8OJ7ih8EE7s?t=19m45s).

What are my interests:

- Editing the presentation with Markdown and HTML
- Adding HTML/JavaScript/CSS blocks of code
- Generating previews of the blocks of code I want
- Getting some kind of **presenter view** in parallel with the presentation itself

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially, questions here are expected to be mostly self-contained, i.e. explicitely list all requirements. A "please look here(link) and there(link) for what I need" is insufficient, though it's fine to include links for *further* reference.

Comment: "What software do they use for" is off-topic here.

Comment: I want a software to be able to do what they do. Why is asking for recommendations off-topic on a website called "Software Recommendations"?

Comment: It was off topic before you edited this question because you expected us to know why they used. This site, if you look at other questions and the help centre, is for recommending software with specific requirements. Otherwise, you might as well google for a program, or comment on that video. You're new revision is much better because it tell us what *exactly* you want. Hope you see why Izzy and Jan said what they did now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced similar problems with web-based markdown editors (id est, not supporting live previews or Github-flavoured markdown), so [I've built my own widget](https://github.com/nigelnquande/mdeditor), based on [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org/) [Extra](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown-extra) and [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) (for MD to PDF output, via HTML).

You're welcome to adapt it to your own purposes.

If you're looking for desktop-based software, I recommend [Atom](https://atom.io/) (wouldn't launch for me on Debian), [Remarkable](http://remarkableapp.net/) (GNU/Linux only) or [Markdown Pad](http://markdownpad.com/) (Windows). All of these editors support live previews, Markdown Extra and Github syntax.